# Designing a PDF in Photoshop and embedding Links in PDF

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pdf-generation, photoshop

I have designed a presentation in Photoshop now i want to export each group from the File into a slide in the PDF format. I want to add links to certain text on the Design as well.

I have saved the file as a Photoshop editable PDF. But when i open it in Acrobat i am not able to add links to the text and it says the text is not editable.

Also i want to make sure the text is searchable in the PDF.

Comment: @yms okay which is the best way do it then? Do i need to use illustrator only?

Comment: That would be a good idea.

Comment: how do i add links into the PDF which are text?

Comment: I am not an expert in Illustrator, but a quick search on google shows this: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Hyperlink-in-Illustrator

Comment: How is this related to software development? I'm sure there are forums where people know more about design applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add links or text to your PDF then use Photoshop to add any text. Otherwise save it as a different file type which will make it easier for other programs to edit.